# Shellscript how to get output into input

Tags: amazon-web-services, sh

I followed this guide (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) to setup cross account acces between my dev and prod account. I want my codebuild in my dev environment to upload to either my dev or prod s3 bucket. When I run

aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::705245353535:role/assumedRole" --role-session-name "tmp-codebuild-update-prod"

I get a response with new credentials for the newly assumed role like this:

```
{
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY",
        "SessionToken": "AQoDYXdzEGcaEXAMPLE2gsYULo+Im5ZEXAMPLEeYjs1M2FUIgIJx9tQqNMBEXAMPLE
CvSRyh0FW7jEXAMPLEW+vE/7s1HRpXviG7b+qYf4nD00EXAMPLEmj4wxS04L/uZEXAMPLECihzFB5lTYLto9dyBgSDy
EXAMPLE9/g7QRUhZp4bqbEXAMPLENwGPyOj59pFA4lNKCIkVgkREXAMPLEjlzxQ7y52gekeVEXAMPLEDiB9ST3Uuysg
sKdEXAMPLE1TVastU1A0SKFEXAMPLEiywCC/Cs8EXAMPLEpZgOs+6hz4AP4KEXAMPLERbASP+4eZScEXAMPLEsnf87e
NhyDHq6ikBQ==",
        "Expiration": "2014-12-11T23:08:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE"
    }
}
```

Now the question is, what is the best way to set these credentials with the shell script on code build?

I need to do something like:

```
set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
set AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=AQoDYXdzEGcaEXAMPLE2gsYULo+Im5ZEXAMPLEeYjs1M2FUIgIJx9tQqNMBEXAMPLECvS
Ryh0FW7jEXAMPLEW+vE/7s1HRpXviG7b+qYf4nD00EXAMPLEmj4wxS04L/uZEXAMPLECihzFB5lTYLto9dyBgSDyEXA
MPLEKEY9/g7QRUhZp4bqbEXAMPLENwGPyOj59pFA4lNKCIkVgkREXAMPLEjlzxQ7y52gekeVEXAMPLEDiB9ST3UusKd
EXAMPLE1TVastU1A0SKFEXAMPLEiywCC/Cs8EXAMPLEpZgOs+6hz4AP4KEXAMPLERbASP+4eZScEXAMPLENhykxiHen
DHq6ikBQ==
```

but how do I get these values? What is the step in between? How do I extract wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY ?

Comment: You can use jq to parse the JSON response you receive by calling the `aws sts assume-role` command and then assign parsed values to environment variables.

Comment: Its ok, its from the AWS documentation

Comment: `set` isn't how you create an environment variable. Use `export` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
cred=$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::705245353535:role/assumedRole" --role-session-name "tmp-codebuild-update-prod")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $cred | jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey' | sed 's/"//g')
echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY # will show the secret access key
```

Explanation
`jq '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey'` use jq to parse the json file and get the SecretAccessKey
`sed 's/"//g'` use sed to remove the double quotes.